# Need exact location of deviceready() in cordova.js

Tags: javascript, cordova

The below code returns me the cordova object. By using the object I am accessing cordava.js

```
<script>
    function onLoad()
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(cordova), false);
</script>
```

Now my query is, from the eventlistener it calls deviceready function. I am asking here where is deviceready function definition. Where can i find this.

Answer (score 0):

`onDeviceready` is a callback function which tells you cordova is ready. So you should define it and write your code related with cordova inside it.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(cordova), false);

function onDeviceReady(cordova) {
 //your code goes here

}
```